# Inflated LinearLayout won't show up in another LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml, dynamically-generated, layout-inflater

I have a main screen that has 3 views:
A "GO" button and an EditText bar at the top (all in a weighted horizontal LinearLayout), and one vertical LinearLayout underneath. In this vertical LinearLayout (current_actions_queue), I am to add ActionHolder objects.

ActionHolder objects extend LinearLayout. Within this class, a view is inflated from xml. The xml's root is *another* LinaearLayout filled with its own goodies.

When the user hits the GO button, an instantiated ActionHolder is added to the current_actions_queue. Yet nothing shows up. I have debugged for over a day now and I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Here is what happens when the user hits GO:

```
   /**
    * Begins the action chosen by the user. Places the action in a view in the
    * main layout.
    * 
    * @param view
    */
   public void beginNewAction(View view) {
      EditText actionToBegin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.action_to_begin);
      String actionName = actionToBegin.getText().toString();
      if (actionName.length() == 0)
         return;
      Action action = user.getDictionary().getAction(actionName.toUpperCase());

      if (currentActionsQueue.contains(action)) {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Action already started!");
         AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
         dialog.show();
         return;
      }
      if (currentActionsQueue.size() == ActiveMenuActivity.MULTITASK_LIMIT) {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Multitask limit reached!");
         AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
         dialog.show();
         return;
      }

      currentActionsQueue.add(action);

      ActionHolder holder = new ActionHolder(this);
      holder.initiate(action);
      LinearLayout currentActionsFrame = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.current_action_queue_view);
      currentActionsFrame.addView(holder);
   }
```

Here is the ActionHolder class:

```
public class ActionHolder extends LinearLayout {

   private Action action;
   private String timer;
   public static final int ACTION_TITLE = 0, ACTION_TIMER = 1,
         PAUSEANDPLAY_BTN = 2, FINISH_BTN = 3;
   private View view;



   public ActionHolder(Context context) {
      super(context);
   }



   public ActionHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
      super(context, attr);
   }



   public ActionHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attr, defStyle);
   }



   public void initiate(Action input) {
      this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      action = input;
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_holder_layout, this, true);

      TextView actionTitle = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(com.tonimiko.mochi_bean.R.id.action_holder_title);
      actionTitle.setText(action.getActionName());
      actionTitle.setId(ActionHolder.ACTION_TITLE);

      TextView actionTimer = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.action_holder_timer);
      actionTimer.setId(ActionHolder.ACTION_TIMER);

      Button pauseBtn = (Button) view
            .findViewById(com.tonimiko.mochi_bean.R.id.pause_and_play_timer_btn);
      pauseBtn.setId(ActionHolder.PAUSEANDPLAY_BTN);

      Button finishBtn = (Button) view
            .findViewById(com.tonimiko.mochi_bean.R.id.finish_activity_button);
      finishBtn.setId(ActionHolder.FINISH_BTN);
   }



   @Override
   protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

}
```

And here is the XML to be inflated in every ActionHolder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/test_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margins"
    android:background="#90A0AA"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/layout_margins" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_holder_titlebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/action_holder_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Action Title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/action_holder_title_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/action_holder_timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="0:00" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_holder_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pause_and_play_timer_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Pause" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finish_activity_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Finish" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in your ActionHolder class you have an empty definition for `onLayout`. This is likely the problem. Either add call to `super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)` in your definition or remove the definition from your subclass. Hope this helps.

Comment: That. Was. IT! I KNEW it was going to be something ridiculously simple. ~_~ Thank you. I shan't be ignoring overridden methods ever again.